# Convert time/date from factor

Tags: r

I wish to convert a time from a factor to a date.

For a sample dataframe:

```
date.time <- structure(list(date = structure(c(1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
                                  1L, 1L), .Label = "02/02/2013", class = "factor"), time = structure(1:9, .Label = c("07:55:40", 
                                                                                                                      "07:55:50", "07:56:00", "07:56:10", "07:56:20", "07:56:30", "07:56:40", 
                                                                                                                      "07:56:50", "07:57:00"), class = "factor")), .Names = c("date", 
                                                                                                                                                                              "time"), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -9L))
```

I wish to learn how to convert the date and time columns to a true date/time (i.e. not factors).

Can somebody explain why this wouldn't work?

```
date.time$time <- as.POSIXlt(date.time$time, format="%H:%M:%S")
```

From what I understand POSIXlt needs a time and date - is that right? When I run this code it adds today's date.

Is it possible to: (a) convert the two columns individually to date and time columns and (b) integrate them together to form a time and date column?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sorry missed that you wanted to combine the two columns. Try

```
date.time$date.time <- paste(as.character(date.time$date), as.character(date.time$time))
date.time$date.time <- as.POSIXlt(date.time$date.time, format="%d/%m/%Y %H:%M:%S")
date.time
class(date.time$date.time)

> date.time
        date     time           date.time
1 02/02/2013 07:55:40 2013-02-02 07:55:40
2 02/02/2013 07:55:50 2013-02-02 07:55:50
3 02/02/2013 07:56:00 2013-02-02 07:56:00
4 02/02/2013 07:56:10 2013-02-02 07:56:10
5 02/02/2013 07:56:20 2013-02-02 07:56:20
6 02/02/2013 07:56:30 2013-02-02 07:56:30
7 02/02/2013 07:56:40 2013-02-02 07:56:40
8 02/02/2013 07:56:50 2013-02-02 07:56:50
9 02/02/2013 07:57:00 2013-02-02 07:57:00
> class(date.time$date.time)
[1] "POSIXlt" "POSIXt"
```

Comment: Thanks - that's really good to know.  I also want to just have the time (not date) formatted correctly.  Is that not possible without a corresponding date?

Comment: Not to my knowledge. In such a data structure, how would time calculations that span midnight be handled?

Comment: Fair enough.  If I wanted to add 10 minutes to my date.time column - is this possible?  Before I was using... >> library(chron) >> date.time$Time <- times(as.character(date.time$Time)) >> date.time$EndTime <- activity$Time + times("00:00:10")... but this isn't working anymore.  How do I work adding time to a POSIXlt date?

Comment: Sure, `date.time$date.time + 600`. It's worth reading the documentation for caveats about date and time representations in R. `?POSIXlt`

Answer (score 3):

you can also try the package `lubridate`

```
library(lubridate)
dmy(date.time$date)
[1] "2013-02-02 UTC" "2013-02-02 UTC" "2013-02-02 UTC" "2013-02-02 UTC" "2013-02-02 UTC" "2013-02-02 UTC" "2013-02-02 UTC" "2013-02-02 UTC" "2013-02-02 UTC"
hms(date$time)
[1] "7H 55M 40S" "7H 55M 50S" "7H 56M 0S"  "7H 56M 10S" "7H 56M 20S" "7H 56M 30S" "7H 56M 40S" "7H 56M 50S" "7H 57M 0S"
```