# How to Convert and Search through Time Strings in R?

Tags: r, date, time

I have date/time for something given as strings of the form "2012-12-11 10:01:37 -0800". I'm just wondering how I would convert this to a date/time value, and also if there was any way to sort a DF by year or month. Thank you!

Comment: This may also help: http://stackoverflow.com/q/29791918/2633645. There will be lots of answers on this topic on SO.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just need to use as.POSIXct() to convert the string into a POSIXct class and now you can manipulate into any form of time you like.

```
> as.POSIXct("2012-12-11 10:01:37 -0800")
[1] "2012-12-11 10:01:37 EST"
> month(as.POSIXct("2012-12-11 10:01:37 -0800"))
[1] 12
> day(as.POSIXct("2012-12-11 10:01:37 -0800"))
[1] 11
> year(as.POSIXct("2012-12-11 10:01:37 -0800"))
[1] 2012
```

Comment: Thanks! Didn't realize that R would recognize it in this format, last project I had to reformat all of the dates significantly before getting R to read it properly

Comment: Yep. Very helpful. Between the packages that are available like lubridate and chron there is very little with date and time output that can not be read easily. Sometimes you have to use something like strsplit() which breaks a sting into two pieces. Good luck and enjoy R.